# Get data from a TextInput from another class kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I want to print what I write in a TextInput that is in another class, I have an MDDialog which has a TextInput that is located in another class and what I want is to print what I write but not prints nothing is as if the text of the TextInput is not updated, help please

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

KV = '''
<Content>
    orientation: "vertical"
  
  
  

    MDTextField:
        id: t1
        hint_text: "Write"


FloatLayout:

    MDFlatButton:
        text: "PRESS"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: app.show_confirmation_dialog()
        
  
'''


class Content(BoxLayout):
    pass


class Example(MDApp):
    dialog = None

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def show_confirmation_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Example:",
                type="custom",
                auto_dismiss=False,
                content_cls=Content(),
                buttons=[   
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="PRINT", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,on_press=self.haha
                    ),
                ],
            )
        self.dialog.open()
    def haha(self,*args):
        print("Content: "+Content().ids.t1.text)
        
Example().run()
```

When I pressed on PRINT I receive:

```
INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
Content: 
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
[INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] exiting mainloop and closing.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

KV = '''
<Content>
    orientation: "vertical"
    MDTextField:
        id: t1
        hint_text: "Write"

FloatLayout:
    MDFlatButton:
        text: "PRESS"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: app.show_confirmation_dialog()
        
'''

class Content(BoxLayout):
    pass


class Example(MDApp):
    dialog = None
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def show_confirmation_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Example:",
                type="custom",
                auto_dismiss=False,
                content_cls=Content(),
                buttons=[   
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="PRINT", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,on_press=self.haha
                    ),
                ],
            )
        self.dialog.open()
    def haha(self,*args):
        print("Content: "+ self.dialog.content_cls.ids.t1.text)
        
Example().run()
```